# Can Resharper 9 perform pattern search and replace on HTML markup?

Tags: html, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, resharper

I am in the process of restructuring large amounts of MVC code to use Bootstrap. The process is very tedious and error prone because it's easy to clobber the markup. The majority of the code, however, is structurally identical and it could be at least partially automated. If I could somehow search the HTML structure,

```
  <div class="header">
        <div class="content">
        <h1 class="big">@Model.Foo </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

with

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    @Model.Foo;
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand Resharper 9 has structural search and replace, but I couldn't find any documentation for it. I would guess that this feature would work for HTML, since Resharper can detect errors in the markup based on nesting.

EDIT: 
I found some documentation on "Search with Pattern", but upon trying it, I couldn't get it to work at all following the examples. In particular, putting any value "CSS Selector" field ignored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. In the search pattern dialog, make sure HTML is selected as the target language, and then just type the first HTML block in as the search pattern. You don't mention if the first block is an example, or exactly the code you want to search for. If it's an example, you'll need to add placeholders for other attributes and elements.

Then put the second block in the replace field. Again, if it's verbatim HTML, just copy it in. Otherwise, you can use the placeholders from the search pattern to fill the captured values in.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Do you know of anywhere where I can find good documentation on this? I was only able to find a blog on Resharper's site and as I mentioned, none of the examples worked for me. The placeholders were grayed out. Moreover, can you recommend a tool or another product that can do this?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know any other tool that works like this. I think it's a pretty impressive technology, and we certainly don't shout about it enough. There are a few [doc pages here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html) (expand the item in the tree view), but not much else, other than some blog posts.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I just realized that they may already have some search patterns stored somewhere that Resharper uses internally. Perhaps I can use it as a basis for my needs? Is there a directory where they keep them?

Comment: Sadly, no, ReSharper doesn't have any patterns available to browse. We use the feature internally, but the patterns are hardcoded into the source.